# Volume which is closer to centre than the vertices and similarily which is closer to centre than the sides of a cube.

Tags: geometry

Consider a cube whose vertices are $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ Denote the centre of cube to be $O$ Find the volume of the locus of points $X$ inside the cube such that $\min [d(A,X), d(B,X), d(C,X), d(D,X),d(E,X),d(F,X),d(G,X),d(H,X)] \geq d(O,X)$ where $d(A,B)$ denotes distance between points $A$ and $B$ . Also solve for similar setup just that this time points should be closer to centre than any sides of cube.

> What i did for first one was first divide the sube into 8 equal cubes by cutting from mid planes , now we can argue that if a point X satisfy the condition from one of the 8 cubes , by rotational symmetry it must be same for all such other 7 points on the other cubes. So one can just focus on a single cube and after that we just need to copy paste it into other cubes . But the problem i am facing is we need to take several >><<<== cases for every d(..,X) term and check if always the greater than ,less than are always obeyed . As such i got it by that method , but in general for other problems and setup similar to this i think there must be a really elegant way to solve it . And for secons part what i considered was a section of cube ( a square part in that area which is closer to centre than the sides is a parabola whose directrix are the sides . But the volume finding is i am not getting as the paraboloid volume i am not able to calculate .

Comment: For the first part you should get a truncated octahedron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of the question, we can, as you suggest, consider the cube to be divided into eight equal cubes. Let the origin be at the centre $O$ and the opposite vertex $A$ to have coordinates $(1,1,1)$. We can label this cube $OPQRTUAS$ with $P$ on the $x$ axis, $R$ on the $y$ axis and $T$ on the $z$ axis.

The locus of points where $d(O,X)=d(A,X)$ is then given by $$x^2+y^2+z^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2$$
$$\implies 2x+2y+2z-3=0$$

This is a plane which cuts the sides $PQ,RQ.SR,ST,TU$ and $UP$ at their midpoints this forming a regular hexagon.

This plane divides the cube into two congruent volumes. Therefore the required volume is exactly **half** the volume of the original cube.

For the second part, you might like to consider posting this as a separate question.